# mongodb get last inserted document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor code tries to find the last document in a collection.

```
.find({userId: this.userId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 1});
```

But since all the documents are in chronological order, I thought to remove the createdAt field, so once that is 'deleted', Is there a "not expensive" way to return just the last entered document?  Thanks

```
{userId: 'someId', info: 'someInfo'}
myCol.findLast().info;              <--- my wish list
```

[$last(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) in the docs first does sorting among other things

**edit**
An attempt to utilise the idea given by Stephen Woods;

server.js

```
MyCol._ensureIndex({createdAt: -1});
MyCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
  createdAt = Date.now();
});
Meteor.publish('myCol', function () {
  return MyCol.findOne({userId: this.userId});
});
```

Comment: The same sort-limit stuff, but using `_id`: `{sort: {_id: -1}, limit: 1}`. It is a unique index, so should be quite cheap.

Comment: `_id` is not sorted chronologically. Also you can `.findOne()` with a `$sort`.

Comment: @MichelFloyd But it _is_ monotonically increasing, since it starts with a 4 byte value of the TS and ends with a 3-byte counter, with the initial random value changing at the begin of each second. Note that sorting by Id uses the actual values, not the string representation show in a result set. Actually, it is exactly the fact that ObjectIds are monotonically increasing makes them a bad shard key, if not hashed.

Comment: @AlexBlex Extremely elegant solution, you should make it a proper answer with an example, maybe.

Comment: I just tried this with an existing collection and verified that order of `_id`s when sorting by `_id` does not match `createdDate` at all.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - it might be that you're thinking of native MongoDB `ObjectId`s. Meteor uses the random package to generate alphanumeric `_id`s.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Oh, wow. Yes, I was thinking in native Mongo. My bad. Have to find out more about that. o.O Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: FYI. You can switch out the default "string based" Meteor `_id` generation for a MongoDB style `ObjectId` instead. You could also replace the generation of `_id` values with anything monotonically increasing ( such as a numeric counter ) as well. Both would then make `_id` sort's valid.

Comment: @BlakesSeven  [idGeneration](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) is either random string or random Mongo.ObjectId, could you show in code how to replace the generation of _id with an autoCounter 1,2,3,...? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that by *expensive* you mean execution time. In that case, you want a `createdAt` field, a secondary index on `createdAt`, and to use a `findOne()` statement. To create the index on `createdAt` for your collection, do:

```
myCol._ensureIndex({ createdAt: -1 });
```

Then in your publish:

```
Meteor.publish('myCol', function () {
  return MyCol.find({userId: this.userId}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I need help formelise the syntax. please see my edit. thx

Comment: For sure index the key!

Comment: @FredJ. you can extend Meteor collections to support your own methods as you describe, see https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models

Comment: @StephenWoods publish must return a cursor or array of cursors.