# Meteor reactive publish

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code displays a message on a `headerLabel` on a template, the server and/or the client changes the message by inserting a new message in `HeaderLabelCol` mongo collection and expect the client template to change since it publishes the last inserted document.

I was able to insert a new message using the client browser but did not show till I refreshed the page which may indicate that the reactiveness chain is broken somewhere. What is the problem? How can it be fixed? Thanks

```
//client.js
Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function () {
    return HeaderLabelCol.findOne() ? HeaderLabelCol.findOne().headerLabel : 'Make a selection';
  }
});

//server.js
HeaderLabelCol = new Mongo.Collection('headerLabelCol');
Meteor.publish('headerLabelCol', function () {
  return HeaderLabelCol.find({userId: this.userId}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
});

HeaderLabelCol._ensureIndex({createdAt: -1});
HeaderLabelCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
});
HeaderLabelCol.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the condition in your helper as well.

```
//client.js
Template.header.helpers({
    headerLabel: function () {
        var result = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
        return result ? result.headerLabel : 'Make a selection';
    }
});
```

Comment: Why sort at the client since the index was sorted all ready by the server which I hopefully done correctly with my [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36185753/5047454) post

Comment: @FredJ.In many real world large applications, There can many different subscriptions returning a collection's data in the same page. Lets say, a template has 2 child templates. `template1` subscribes to `pub1` and `template2` subscribes to `pub2`. If both `pub1` and `pub2` return data from `collection1` and sorts then using different property (one by `createdAt` and other by `_id`, then the minimongo will mix the results on the client side. So it cannot always be guaranteed that server sorting is maintained on client. So you need to do filtering and sorting again as done on the server as well.